# CouchDB 0.11 on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, couchdb

i have successfully installed CouchDB 0.11 on Ubuntu 10.04 based on the [Installation instruction in couchdb wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Installing_on_Ubuntu) for ubuntu 10.04. with appending " --bindir=/usr/bin --sbindir=/usr/sbin --localstatedir=/var --sysconfdir=/etc" in ./configure

And CouchDB is running successfully and got " {"couchdb":"Welcome","version":"0.11.0"}"

But the Test Suite is not running successfully, with being freeze in the first task "basics".

Any support to solve that and making the Test Suite running smoothly on Ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: The same happened to me, looking at the quearies with wireshark, it stops on a simple map function, I wonder why

Comment: also i got form http://localhost:5984/_status response {"error":"error","reason":"illegal_database_name"}
while all databases names is so normal.

Answer (score 3):

I experienced the same issue, with the Test Suite freezing on the first "basics". CPU was very high and the log was littered with logs like this

```
[Wed, 26 May 2010 17:34:18 GMT] [debug] [<0.1014.0>] OS Process Start :: #Port<0.2005>

[Wed, 26 May 2010 17:34:18 GMT] [debug] [<0.1014.0>] OS Process
#Port<0.2005> Input  :: ["reset",{"reduce_limit":true}]

[Wed, 26 May 2010 17:34:18 GMT] [error] [<0.786.0>] OS Process Error <0.1014.0> :: {os_process_error,{exit_status,127}}
```

I was able to fix the issue when I ran couchdb manually, with LD_LIBRARY_PATH set to the lib directory for xulrunner-devel, which was one of the prerequisites I believe.

```
# export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/xulrunner-devel-1.9.2.3/lib
# /usr/local/bin/couchdb
```

All tests ran successfully when started like this.

EDIT:
A more permanent fix is to add the above xulrunner-devel path to a file under /etc/ld.so.conf.d. On my machine I made a file **/etc/ld.so.conf.d/couchdb.conf** with the contents

```
/usr/lib/xulrunner-devel-1.9.2.3/lib
```

Then I ran **ldconfig** and restarted CouchDB.

Sidenote: When I previously started CouchDB manually I did it as root, which caused some permission issues, so make sure that all permissions are set correctly where you installed CouchDB.